# My dropdown menu keeps appearing when I don't want it too

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown

So, I got a navigation bar with dropdown menus. Whenever I move my cursor where the drop-down menu is hidden, it opens, and I need to disable that without disabling the drop-down menu as a whole. Any tips on how to do that?

If you want to go ahead and look at the latest version of my website can be found below.

Here's the link: https://p1ayerone.github.io/

And here's the CSS code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap');

:root {
  --background: rgba(54, 57, 63, .85);
}
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: url(../../img/bg/bg.png) fixed center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: silver;
}


.content {
  height: 200vh;
  background-size: cover;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

/* navigation styles start here */

header {
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  position: fixed;
}

.logo {
  margin: 0;
  color: silver;
  list-style: none;
}

.img-logo {
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.nav-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.nav-toggle-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 1em;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: left;
  margin-top: 3.5%;
}

.nav-toggle-label span, 
.nav-toggle-label span::before,
.nav-toggle-label span::after {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  height: 2px;
  width: 2em;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-toggle-label span::before,
.nav-toggle-label span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}

.nav-toggle-label span::before {
  bottom: 7px;
}

.nav-toggle-label span::after {
  top: 7px;
}

.nav {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  background: var(--background);
  padding-bottom: 1.7%;
}

.nav::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.nav-main {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: -21px;
  padding-bottom: -15px;
}

.nav-main-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12rem;
  position: relative;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-main a {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #eee;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.nav-main-item a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

.nav-main-item:hover > * {
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0;
  }

.navi-main-item {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: var(--background);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.more-main-item {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: var(--background);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.nav-toggle:checked ~ nav {
    transform: scale(1,1);
}

.nav-toggle:checked ~ nav a {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.destiny-intro-p {
  padding-left: 100px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.destiny-intro-h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.body-block {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 6%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {

.nav-toggle-label {
  display: none;
}

header {
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  position: fixed;
}

.logo {
  margin: 0;
  color: silver;
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 15;
}

.nav {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  background: var(--background);
}

.nav::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.nav-main {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-main-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10rem;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-main a {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.nav-main-item a:hover {
  background-color: silver;
}

.nav-main-item:hover > * {
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0;
  }

.navi-main-item {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: var(--background);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  }
    
  .Discord {
      float: right;
   }
   
   .gif-Destiny {
       width: 200px;
       float: right;
       color: silver;
       }
       
   .Zachary {
       color: black;
       text-decoration: none;
   }
     
  .introduction {
    color: black;
  }

.footer {
    background-color: #1F2E4B;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: center;
    margin-top: 100%;
  }

.CbZD{
    color: #00FFFF;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}

.Discord {
  float: right;
}

.img-Destiny {
   padding-top: 0px;
   width: 300px;
   float: right;
   color: black;
   }
   
.Zachary {
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
}

.introduction {
   color: black;
}

.footer {
   background-color: #1F2E4B;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 20px;
   float: center;
}

.CbZD{
   color: #00FFFF;
   font-size: 30px;
}

/* Videos */

.tse {
  color: #07FC1B;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Characters */

.img-TBG {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
}

/* Applications */

.silver-box {
  background-color: silver;
  color: black;
  height: 1400px;
  width: 640px;
}

/* About Me */

.abtme {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Links */

.contact-me {
  color: silver;
}

.gmail-footer {
  color: silver;
}

.twitter-footer {
  color: silver;
}

/* Contact */

.contact-title {
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 4s ease-in-out;
}

.contact-title h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: -10px;
}

.contact-title h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

form {
  margin-top: 50px;
  transition: all 4s ease-in-out;
}

.form-control {
  width: 600px;
  background: var(--background);
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

input {
  height: 45px;  
}

form .submit {
  background: #ff5722;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

form .submit:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using opacity:0 and opacity:1 to display the dropdown, you can use display:none and display:inline-block. When using opacity, it doesn't remove the element from the page, which is why the dropdown would appear when hovering in that area.

Can read more about this here https://magnusbenoni.com/difference-between-display-visibility-opacity/

```
 .nav-main-item:hover > .navi-main-item {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0;
 }

.navi-main-item {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      top: 100%;
      z-index: -1;
      background: var(--background);
      box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  }
```